# Como criar constantes em Java?

Tags: java, classes, constantes, campos

Uma constante em java não pode ser alterada, mas pode ser atribuído um valor inicial através de outra variável ?

Por exemplo, se tivermos no nosso programa um método que calcula hipoteticamente a taxa de importação de um produto através da localização dele e retorna um valor `double`, porém esse valor não pode ser mudado no decorrer do programa, deve permanecer igual ao valor retornado inicialmente para poder ser aplicado em outros lugares de diversas formas possíveis.

Então, eu posso atribuir o valor que ele retornou a uma constante? Quais as maneiras de "inalterar" um valor que foi calculado a partir de outro(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java não possui constantes, mas nem é oque você deseja. Java possui variáveis somente leitura, ou como ela gosta de chamar que seu valor é finalizado, então ele pode ser colocado na variável durante a construção do objeto, depois ele não pode mais ser alterado. Faz-se assim:

```
public final BigDecimal taxa;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Constant.java).

O segredo aí é o `final` que não permite a variável ser alterada, a não ser dentro do construtor.

Usei `BigDecimal` porque se é um valor que será usado para cálculo monetário provavelmente necessidade exatidão, coisa que o `double` não dá.

Se quiser um controle maior e permite alterar sob certas circunstâncias aí não tem jeito. A solução seria o uso de um método *setter* que analisa se pode ou não alterar e faz a alteração ou não, ou ainda não ter um método desse e só internamente ele tomar uma decisão de alteração em algum caso, mas nunca invocado diretamente pelo consumidor da classe com intuito apenas de alterar seu valor. Esse é um caso que pode ser necessário se só sabe do valor depois do objeto construído.